# html5 pattern for usa canada zip code upper and lower case

Tags: regex, html

```
<input type="input"  id="zip" name="zip" pattern="^(^[0-9]{5}|^[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{5}[-][0-9]{4}|[A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z] [0-9][A-Za-z][0-9])$" data-pattern-error="For United State accepted: xxxxx or xxxxx-xxxx for Canada  accepted: x1x1x1 x1x 1x1" placeholder="xxxxx-xxxx or X1X1X1 X1X 1X1"  data-required-error="Please provide your zip / postal code">
```

its working okay for lowercase how to make it work with both upper and lower case any ideas pls?

Comment: FYI `{1}` is redundant as it's the default. Also, by default, `pattern` adds anchors so `^` and `$` aren't needed.

Comment: will removing {1} fix it . ?

Comment: "([-1-9]{5}|[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9]{5}[-][0-9]{4}|[A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z][0-9])" not working yet

Comment: x1x 1x1 shows as valid but X1X 1X1 not valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some notes on your regex:

- `{1}` is redundant as it's default regex behaviour
- You can combine options and make parts optional using `?` as the regex below shows
- `^` and `$` anchors are the default behaviour of the `pattern` attribute.

---

The regex below is a shortened version of yours with other improvements

```
\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?|[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z] ?\d[a-zA-Z]\d
```

- Match either of the following

  - `\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?` Match the following

    - `\d{5}` Match 5 digits
    - `(?:-\d{4})?` Optionally match `-` followed by 4 digits
  - `[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z] ?\d[a-zA-Z]\d` Match the following

    - `[a-zA-Z]` Match an ASCII letter
    - `\d` Match a digit
    - `[a-zA-Z]` Match an ASCII letter
    - `?` Optionally match a space
    - `\d` Match a digit
    - `[a-zA-Z]` Match an ASCII letter
    - `\d` Match a digit

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" pattern="\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?|[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z] ?\d[a-zA-Z]\d"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: fantastic thank you so much, worked like a charm, appreciate for making clear about default behaviour of pattern